# increment the field with additions of new values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a phpscript which takes values (Manually entered) and inserts into the column in the database. Now I want to know how would I be adding new values to the existing values for the same card number entered.

```
if(isset($_POST['insert-btn'])){
  @$cardnumber=$_POST['cardnumber'];
  @$amount=$_POST['amount'];                            
  if($cardnumber=="" || $amount==""){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Insert values in all fields")</script>';
  }
  else{
    $query = "insert into Client_Details values('$cardnumber',$amount/2)";
    $query_run=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if($query_run){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Values inserted successfully")</script>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Values not inserted successfully")</script>';
    }
  }
}   
?>
```

For example , I have

```
card number: _________

Sale value: __________
```

Now for the same card number the sale value entered every different time should be added. If anybody can help me with that. It would be helpful.

Comment: show your code to help us giving a good solution

Comment: I have added a picture in the query statement the update is not working right

Comment: No pictures of code. Put the actual code here.

Comment: I added the part of the code

Answer (score 0):

Before you insert data into DB, check whether a record for the card number already exists in the DB.
If it exists, use UPDATE query else use INSERT query.

Try the below code:

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['insert-btn']))
    {
    @$cardnumber = $_POST['cardnumber'];
    @$amount = $_POST['amount'];
    if ($cardnumber == "" || $amount == "")
        {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Insert values in all fields")</script>';
        }
      else
        {
        $newQuery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Client_Details WHERE cardnumber='" . $cardnumber . "'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($newQuery) > 0)
            {
            $query = "UPDATE Client_Details SET amount = amount + '" . $amount . "' WHERE cardnumber = '" . $cardnumber . "'";
            }
          else
            {
            $query = "INSERT into Client_Details values('$cardnumber',$amount/2)";
            }

        $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        if ($query_run)
            {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Values inserted successfully")</script>';
            }
          else
            {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Values not inserted successfully")</script>';
            }
        }
    }
```

*Modify the table name and column names accordingly

Comment: appreciated the response. I'll try it out

Comment: So I did make the changes but it's giving me the white screen of php page now. hmm I saw your code everything seems right though

Comment: so your code is totally right. the only thing causing the white screen was            $query = "INSERT into Client_Details values('$cardnumber','$amount/2')";  ****Here**** the '$amount/2' won't be in quotations because it is a number. Thanks a lot

Comment: @surii yeah..sorry about that...I have updated my answer

Comment: @Surii Glad to know that it worked. Please mark the question as solved